# Getting "java.net.UnknownHostException" error on Log Out step in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new in JMeter. Currently I am trying to create load testing scripts using Blazemeter for one of the clients website.

I am getting "java.net.UnknownHostException" on the Log Out step in JMeter.
All other steps I created are getting passed i.e. Launch, Login, Navigation etc.

Only when it comes to Log out step it fails.
Could someone please shed some light on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

I tried correcting the request headers (userid, authorization in my case). Issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

It means that JMeter cannot resolve DNS hostname or IP address of the host you defined in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

Double check it and make sure that it is correct. To be absolutely sure you can just record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium).

If you're able to open it via browser and cannot with JMeter it might mean that the browser uses a proxy, if this is the case you need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server).